# Perl Mojolicious Under

Tags: perl, mojolicious

In order to correctly route the input information within this mojolicious application I am using the 'under' functionality. How come this code doesn't work but the code in the second block does for actually deleting the selected item from the database.

```
 my $r_hostservices = $r->
        under('/hosts_services:host_services_id')->
        to('hosts_services#hosts_services');

 $r_hostservices->
        delete(':hosts_services_id')->
        to('hosts#hosts_services_deletion')->
        name('hosts_services_deletion');
```

The second (working) block is as follows

```
 $r->delete('/hosts_services/:hosts_services_id')->
        to('hosts#hosts_services_deletion')->
        name('hosts_services_deletion');
```

Answer (score 2):

```
package a;
use Mojo::Base 'Mojolicious';

# This method will run once at server start
sub startup {
  my $self = shift;

  # Load configuration from hash returned by config file
  my $config = $self->plugin('Config');

  # Configure the application
  $self->secrets($config->{secrets});

  # Router
  my $r = $self->routes;

  my $ur = $r->under('/foo/:bar');

  $ur->delete()->to('example#two');
  $ur->any()->to('example#one');
}

1;
```

You can always list all defined routes this way:

```
script/a routes
```

This feature very useful for debugging in such situations. You can read more about Mojolicious CLI  here [Mojolicious::Commands](https://mojolicious.org/perldoc/Mojolicious/Commands).

Here comes example output with routes mentioned above:

```
/foo/:bar  *       foobar
  +/       DELETE  
  +/     
*
```

So, we can see, that Mojolicious now will serve url `/foo/:bar/` for `DELETE` and any other request method, but trailing slash is always optional, and `/foo/:bar` will work fine.

In this case: `under('/foo/:bar')->to( example#zero )`, `example#zero` is intermediate destination, so all routes defined under this one, will visit `example#zero` and only after it will continue execution of own destination. So, `under( ... )->to( ... )` can be used for auth and another similar tasks. In my example `under()` used without `to()`.

P.S. Mojolicious comes with wonderful documentation and I encourage everyone to actively use it

[Mojolicious::Routes::Route](https://mojolicious.org/perldoc/Mojolicious/Routes/Route)

[Mojolicious::Guides::Routing](https://mojolicious.org/perldoc/Mojolicious/Guides/Routing)