# Mojolicious routing: over vs. under

Tags: perl, routes, mojolicious

As far as I understood Mojolicious routing the "under" method provides a code sharing method for routes, whereas "over" adds conditions to these routes.
In my application I use the "under" method on all routes under "/" to perform authentication and authorization (saved inside the session), and "over" conditions to check if a user has a certain permission.

Unfortunately Mojolicious checks the condition from "over" first, before executing the shared code from "under" which leads to unauthorized requests every time a user makes an API call where the client does not save the session. Is there any way to achieve what I want, or is this just not the way Mojolicious works with the "over" and "under" routing precedence?

Thank you!

Comment: If you want something to happen first, why don't you use the mechanism that happens first?

Comment: Because the over mechanism is there to add conditions, as the documentation says. Using under adds a shared codebase for routes. Besides, not all endpoints under a specific part of the routing need authorization but authentication.

Comment: Having been authenticated is a condition. But, it sounds like you have some unusual organization in the routing structure, and not knowing that it's difficult to make suggestions.

Comment: So permissions aren't conditions?

Comment: Use 'under' to check authentication for branch of protected routes. Create standalone route for login.

Maybe this answer will be interesting https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43141771/perl-mojolicious-under/62223541
Mojo cmd is awesome!

Comment: Permissions are not conditions. Over is there for routing based on the presence of different headers.