# Introspecting the name of placeholder variables from a Mojolicious controller

Tags: perl, parameters, routes, mojolicious

I have a Mojolicious controller that fires in response to different URL routes. For example, given the URL path:

```
/v1/users/:someid
```

and a controller that fires:

```
sub handle_request ($self) {
     my $place_holder_name = $self->route->??????   # how can I get 'someid'?
     is($place_holder_name, 'someid', 'can access the placeholder name');
}
```

How can I find out the name of the placeholder?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

## Param

These are not currently documented under [`Mojolicious::Routes`](https://metacpan.org/pod/Mojolicious::Routes), so I can see why that's confusing. They're documented under [`Mojolicious::Controller#param`](https://metacpan.org/pod/Mojolicious::Controller#param),

What you have there is a Route param, so you can retreive that value with,

```
$c->param('someid');
```

## Getting All Params Provided to a Controller

Though undocumneted, you can [find the names of the captures in the internal hashref like this,](https://metacpan.org/dist/Mojolicious/source/lib/Mojolicious/Controller.pm#L56)

```perl
$self->stash->{'mojo.captures'};
```

Like this;

```perl
my $params = $self->stash->{'mojo.captures'};
warn for keys %$params;
```

Comment: Thanks Evan - that's a good idea - although the controller may not know the name of the placeholder - as it is a generic controller for multiple routes. 

I'm trying to discover the name of the placeholder from within the controller - so it needs to somehow introspect to pick up the placeholder name. 

I read also that placeholder values are also placed into the stash. I could potentially search for a variable name that appears in the stash as well as in params to resolve the problem but this feels hacky.

Comment: maybe this answer can help? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43141771/perl-mojolicious-under/62223541#62223541

(I mean source code of command that prints out all routes will help)